# Oracle update table adding ID column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In Oracle 11 I have a table without an ID column. I have create it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myDb.mySeq
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NOORDER;

alter table MyTable add(ID NUMBER NOT NULL);
```

But  now i must update all existing record with the new ID column. How I can do it?

Comment: Will that even work? How can you add a NOT NULL column to a table that already contains data?

Comment: Yes. Unless you truncate/delete the existing data, you can never add a not null column.

Comment: Yes, I have a problem creating the column becouse NOT NULL is not possible if a table contains data.

Comment: Add the column without the `not null` constraint, update the data, then add the `not null` constraint.

Comment: Yes, I have just try. Your solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is

```
update mytable set id=mySeq.nextval;
```

Comment: And of course add a trigger that fetches the id for new rows.